# Is there a loadscript equivalent in eth?

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum

I got this error in `eth` client :

> Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: loadscript is not defined

is there a `loadscript` equivalent command in the cpp client `eth`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start eth you should be doing:

```
$ eth

$ geth attach
```

or, if you don't have geth installed yet...

```
$ npm install -g ethereum-console

$ ethconsole
```

This will give you access to loadScript and other useful commands.